# Error 25 enviando mail a smtp.office.365 (Cómo implementar TLS 1.2 en Genexus X Evo3 Framework 3.5)

Tags: .net, genexusxev3

Hace una semana Microsoft cambió a TLS 1.2 su capa de seguridad para envío/recepción de correos electrónicos. Desde ese momento nuestro programa de envío de correos ha dejado de funcionar. Retorna

> error 25 (user or password refused).

¿Alguien sabe cómo debo configurar para arreglar este problema? ¿Puede ser que compilando de nuevo con Framework 4.5 o 4.8 se solucione?
Mi código de conexión es el siguiente:

//  CONEXIÓN VIA SMTP-OFFICE365 DE MICROSOFT //

```
    &smtp.Host='smtp.office365.com'
    &smtp.Sender.Address=trim(&CodMail)
    &smtp.Sender.Name=MailEmpreNom
    &smtp.Authentication=1
    &smtp.UserName='administracio@pares.e.telefonica.net'         
    &smtp.Port=587  //25
    &smtp.Password=trim(&Contrapena)
    &smtp.Secure=1 
    &smtp.ErrDisplay = 0
    &errlogin_num=&smtp.Login()
    &errlogin_text=&smtp.ErrDescription
```

He encontrado algo en la ayuda de Genexus (añadir una etiqueta `<add key="SMTPSession" value="Native" />` en *client.exe.config* pero no ha funcionado, devuelve error 10.

Estoy trabajando en Genexus X Evo 3 WIN.

Answer (score 0):

En el panel de administracion de usuarios, busca el usuario con el que mandas el correo, dentro de su configuración en la pestaña de correo hay aplicaciones de correo, debes habilitar la que dice SMTP autenticado

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero ha tiene seteado ese aspecto. De todas formas, con la nueva política de seguridad de Microsoft Exchange (Oauth 2.0) tendremos que cambiar otras cosas.